# onClick button in adapter

Tags: button, adapter

I have a button in the recyclerview, and I want when I click the button then it will go to the next page. I try like this in my adapter but my app currently force close and in logcat nothing happens..

**CustomerAdapter.java**

```
 public class CustomerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerAdapter.CustomerViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Customer> datasSet;

public CustomerAdapter(ArrayList<Customer> tempData) {
    this.datasSet = tempData;
}

@Override
public CustomerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_customer_index_row, parent, false);

    return new CustomerViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomerAdapter.CustomerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Customer csModel = datasSet.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(csModel.getCustNama());

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("ratri2", "onClick: sukses ");
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, GenerateSpkActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return datasSet.size();
}

public class CustomerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView name;
    public Button button;

    public CustomerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.customer_name);
        button= itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnGenerate);
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: In such cases IDEA shows error message in tooltip or status bar. Also, Alt-Enter allows you brings proposals menu. So far your question lacks the message so you will hardly get a reply on this.

Comment: alt+enter cant not resolve the problem @IliaNedoluzhko

Comment: My main point is to read the error message and add it to your question

Comment: Better practice to put it as text so it will be indexed and available to others through search.